# Uncaught (in promise) Wordpress Admin [Chrome Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (arm64)]

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

I caught this error

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLMJQ.png)

On the WordPress admin dashboard, when running chrome Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (arm64)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try to disable and test your plugin one after the other.... and if nothing new try to update them  one after the other

Comment: @sylvain It doesn't work even if the new install Wordpress with simple theme and few plugin you can caught this error to on Chrome new version, it took at least 5 min then check the console and you will see the error on the admin side.

Comment: The solution to resolve this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72638873/13166204