# Keep getting this console error via Wordpress Admin

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

Uncaught (in promise) {message: 'A listener indicated an asynchronous response by r…age channel closed before a response was received'}message: "A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received"[[Prototype]]: Object
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ geolocation-spoofing.js:17

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an error from an extension, I fixed it by removing Windscribe chrome ex.

Comment: how to know where is `geolocation-spoofing.js`  and where it's getting called from . because I thought it was something in node modules